# Named XML serialization of List

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I derived from `List<int>` and want to XML serilaize with custom names. Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace xmlerror
{
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("Foo")]
    public class Foo : List<int>
    {
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            foo.Add(123);

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                var serilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
                serilizer.Serialize(writer, foo);
                Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <int>123</int>
</Foo>
```

But I want to name the element `<Bar>` instead of `<int>`. I tried the XML attributes `XmlAnyElement` and `XmlArrayItem` but to no end. How can I change the name of the element tags? Do I have to do it manually with `XmlTextWriter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

For example you can implement `IXmlSerializable` interface.

```
[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class Foo : List<int>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Bar");

        while (reader.Name == "Bar")
            this.Add(reader.ReadElementContentAsInt());
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var n in this)
            writer.WriteElementString("Bar", n.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution to use something other than `int`.

```
public class Bar 
{
    public Bar(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public Bar()
    {

    }

    [XmlText]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : List<Bar>
{

}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5vfNny) for a working demo.

As an aside, the `Serializable` attribute is not related to `XmlSerializer` and can be omitted.

Comment: This works too but I decided to use the other answer.